# Running a specific browser NUnit test using the command line

Tags: nunit

I am trying to run the firefox only test using the command line for NUnit but not sure how to. The code is as follow.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
public class TestCases<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{}
```

No problem with NUnit GUI since it is separated, however requirements forces us to run it with the command line. Thanks.

I'm looking into like: nunit.console.exe /fixture:"value" /xml:.. etc.. or any other implementation

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is to specify a category with the driver such as: `[TestFixture(typeof(string), "Chrome")]`

Then you can specify the category on the console arguments with `nunit-console.exe foo.dll /include:Chrome`

Comment: The other thing you could do is use something like SpecFlow which creates categories for the browser automatically: `@Browser:Chrome`